# How to use of an instance of a class in another class

Tags: javascript, class

I have three separate library :

1. Export.js : that written all export methods
2. HamburgerMenu.js : Export.js used here
3. Loding.js : display spiner to prepare export file

Created an instance of `Export.js` in `HamburgerMenu.js` then a method of instance passed through `Loading.js` to run method. But there is an error in `Loding.js` that can not access to `editor` in `Export.js`.

`Export.js` and `Loading.js` hasn't direct relation.

How can i solve it?

#### Export.js

```
class Export {

    constructor(editor) {
        this.editor = editor;
    }

     exportGeometry() {

        var object = this.editor.selected; // return error : editor is undefined
       ...
     }
}
```

#### HamburgerMenu.js

```
import { Export } from './Export';
import { Loading } from './loading';

function HamburgerMenu(editor) {
   var exportModule = new Export(editor);

   var loading = new Loading('Please Wait..', 'Preparing to download ...', 
        exportModule.exportGeometry);
   
}
```

#### Loading

```
class Loading {

    constructor(title, message, Fun) {

        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;

        Fun(); // Fun here is exportGeometry that passed from HamburgerMenu
    }
```

Comment: The `exportModule.exportGeometry` argument should be `() => exportModule.exportGeometry()`

Comment: Also "selected" property on this.editor.selected will be undefined. But you can take care of that after you take care of "this" reference issue.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ it's solved my issue